# "<handler> scriptProcessor could not be found in <fastCGI> application configuration" when accessing PHP script in subfolder

Tags: php, iis, fastcgi

I have a configuration problem with php on IIS 7.5.

It is a practically fresh install made with the MS Web PI on Win7.

I created a simple php testpage. **It works** in the root level `http://localhost/test.php` and in the first sub-level `http://localhost/site/test.php`, but not in `http://localhost/site/subfolder/test.php`, there I get HTTP 500 error:
`<handler> scriptProcessor could not be found in <fastCGI> application configuration`

Everything seems to be configured as specified in http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/fastCgi/application

Could there be some kind of filter that disables processing at specific folder-level / or enable it just in the first 2 levels?

What should I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I copied the files that I had on the previous setup. And the subfolder that was not working had web.config where a different php-cgi.exe was specified.

Basically I now have 64-bit system and the php executable is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe`, I discovered it in the IIS Manager by going to the non-working folder and opening Handler Mappings and checking the value for `PHP_via_FastCGI`, that's when I noticed the old executable in `C:\Program Files\PHP...`

Thanks for your attention :) hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Incase you're facing this issue, ensure your for example web.config handler configuration match one of the fastCGI settings pool e.g if your pool is this

```xml
        <fastCgi>
            <application fullPath="C:\Users\user\Downloads\php7.4\php-cgi.exe" arguments="-d open_basedir=C:\Users\user\Documents\YurWallet\public" maxInstances="0" instanceMaxRequests="10000">
                <environmentVariables>
                    <environmentVariable name="PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" value="10000" />
                </environmentVariables>
            </application>
            <application fullPath="C:\Users\user\Downloads\php7.4\php-cgi.exe" arguments="-d open_basedir=C:\Users\user\Documents\ReadyCash\ReadyCash.Agent.Profiles" maxInstances="0" instanceMaxRequests="10000">
                <environmentVariables>
                    <environmentVariable name="PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" value="10000" />
                </environmentVariables>
            </application>
        </fastCgi>
```

then to use for example the second pool in one of your website then your handle definition must match combo of full path and the argument i.e

```xml
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
      <add name="PHP via FastCGI"
        path="*.php" verb="*"
        modules="FastCgiModule"
        scriptProcessor="C:\Users\user\Downloads\php7.4\php-cgi.exe|-d open_basedir=C:\Users\user\Documents\ReadyCash\ReadyCash.Agent.profiles"
        resourceType="Unspecified"
        requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
```

else IIS will complain of not able to find a processor