# "<handler> scriptProcessor could not be found in <fastCGI> application configuration" when accessing PHP script in subfolder

Tags: php, iis, fastcgi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“<handler> scriptProcessor could not be found in <fastCGI> application configuration” when accessing PHP script in subfolder](https://serverfault.com/questions/271825/handler-scriptprocessor-could-not-be-found-in-fastcgi-application-configurat)

I have a configuration problem with php on IIS 7.5.

It is a practically fresh install made with the MS Web PI on Win7.

I created a simple php testpage. It works in the root level `http://localhost/test.php` and in the first sub-level `http://localhost/site/test.php`, but not in `http://localhost/site/subfolder/test.php`, there I get HTTP 500 error:
`<handler> scriptProcessor could not be found in <fastCGI> application configuration`

Everything seems to be configured as specified in http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/fastCgi/application

Could there be some kind of filter that disables processing at specific folder-level / or enable it just in the first 2 levels?

What should I check?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out I copied the files that I had on the previous setup. And the subfolder that was not working had web.config where a different php-cgi.exe was specified.

Basically I now have 64-bit system and the php executable is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe`, I discovered it in the IIS Manager by going to the non-working folder and opening Handler Mappings and checking the value for `PHP_via_FastCGI`, that's when I noticed the old executable in `C:\Program Files\PHP...`

Thanks for your attention :) hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thx.  Your answer just made me go and look at the right place.  Had the same problem with IIS using the wrong handler.  Deleted the old one and everything started working again.